# Equivalent Observable.fromIterable in Kotlin Coroutine Flow?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I would like to ask how to achieve the below code in Kotlin Flows. If you help, I will be appreciated it.

```
val list = listOf<Int>()
Observable.fromIterable(list)
```

Comment: What do u think about it? It will be cover?
val source = flow { list.forEach { emit(it) } }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `asFlow()` on an Iterable.

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val flow = list.asFlow()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the @Tenfour04's answer is to use `flowOf`:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
flowOf(*list.toTypedArray())
```